# Manage single user account on device

Tags: ios

I have such case in my app. My app communicate with api and after user has logged in app get a json with user information. There is only single user at time who work with app. I have a two conception about where store user data:

1. In UserDefaults or KeyChain
2. Create DB model and use it as singleton

Can you tell me witch option is better? Or maybe you can recommend some other option I haven't considered before.

Thank you for help.

Comment: "Better" depends on requirements.  Do you need secure access?  Is there a lot of data or only small amounts?  Does it have relationships among objects?  ...?

Comment: If with user data you mean passwords or access tokens then I would suggest the keychain. All other data I would save in the app document directory. And depending on the amount and reaction either just serialized objects, coredata or some other data base.

Comment: @PhillipMills **yes**, there is a lot of user data include user picture; and **yes** there are OtherObject-User relation.

Comment: @rckoenes Do you mean create json file with data receive from api and access class to this json file?

Comment: No use `NSCoding` of the model of the response data.